# Passing 1 argument, and it's saying I'm passing 2

Tags: python, parameter-passing

```
import os
import sys

class Corrector:

    def correctAll(dir):
        print "ok"

c = Corrector()
c.correctAll(os.getcwd())
```

This code is printing:

> TypeError: correctAll() takes exactly
>   1 argument (2 given)

but AFAIK `os.getcwd()` returns a single string.. what's wrong here?

Comment: I don't know python, but is it possible that there is a callback param that is passed in by default, along with the param you're passing in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to accept `self` as an argument or use the `staticmethod` decorator.

```
class Corrector:

    def correctAll(self, dir):
        print "ok"
```

or

```
class Corrector:

    @staticmethod
    def correctAll(dir):
        print "ok"
```

The distinction  between the two is if you want the method to have access to the instance that it's called on or not. If so, then use the first one and the the instance will be available as `self`. Otherwise, you can use the second one.

Python methods work by explicitly accepting the object that they are bound to as their first argument (`self` is canonical here but it can really be anything). That argument is then implicitly passed when a call occurs.

Comment: Of course `staticmethod` is not needed as much in Python as in languages that require everything to be in a class...

Answer (score 1):

Your correctAll is missing the `self` parameter: All instance methods must have `self` as its first argument, it means "the object itself"
In other words, `c.correctAll(x)` is like `Corrector.correctAll(c, x)`

Python shell example

```
>>> class Test:
...   def doSomething(s, x): print x
... 
>>> Test().doSomething(1)
1
>>> Test.doSomething(Test(), 1)
1
>>> Test()
<__main__.Test instance at 0xb7793acc>
>>>
```

Working code:

```
import os
import sys

class Corrector:

    def correctAll(self, dir):
        print "ok"

c = Corrector()
c.correctAll(os.getcwd())
```

See also: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html

Answer (score 1):

In python you must accept the instance argument - called `self` - explicitely (while other languages simply provide it automagically). So your method definition must looks like `def correctAll(self, dir)`.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you define `self` in the argument list as well?

```
class Corrector:

    def correctAll(self, dir):
        print "ok"
```

Maybe I'm wrong...